# Open .exe file, change code and run edited code using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a C# project that compiles into .exe. My project changes hardcoded strings (with the help of Roslyn), for example:

```
var a = "Fruits";
//Changes above string to: 
var a = "Fruits and vegetables";
```

The problem is that this only works if I give it .sln path.

```
var solution = await ws.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFilePath);
```

But what I want is that I can modify code when .exe is ran, to change that .exe code not the source code in my solution and then run this modified .exe. Is that possible with Roslyn? If not, is there any other way for me to achieve this?

Comment: you cannot modify a (compiled!!!) assembly, only source-code.

Comment: You can actually modify an assembly, as long as it is not signed, and there are many other limitations. But it is rarely the correct approach. What is the end goal here? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you change the program to pull the values from a text file or database instead of hard-coding them. Then you don't need to - you just edit the text file. This seems like a horribly round-about-way to do something like this. Roslyn is for editing THE CODE, not the DATA

Comment: My goal is to translate (change language) program. I have a text file that I transform into dictionary, and then I can call a function I created TranslateString("") and it does the trick. With Roslyn I wanted to save myself from going through every part of code and manually replace hardcoded string for example: from var fruit = "fruit " to var fruit = TranslateString("fruit").

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828896/can-you-change-code-with-roslyn-only-when-exe-is-executed? If your goal is translation, this is what .resx files and related tooling is for.